# on infinities, sets and limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is it mathematically correct to define the following:

- $[0, \infty] \equiv \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}{[0, n]}$
- $[0, \infty) \equiv \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}{[0, n)}$

More generally, I'm concerned with the "boundary" between the arbitrarily large and the notion of infinity.  Is there some good philosophical treatment of this sort of conundrum?

Comment: Even if it were correct, why would you? The first one makes no sense and the second one is just $\{x: x\ge 0\}$.

Comment: You can define stuff as you best see fit. The important part is that, then, you don't expect the first one to be consistent with $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n=\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup\limits_{k\ge n} A_k$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap\limits_{k\ge n} A_k$.

Comment: For [0,oo], look up extended reals.